# Navigation properties and cascade on delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade, navigation-properties

I am using EF5 fluent-api to try to set up relationships/constraints between several tables, and I want these relationships to include cascade on delete and I think I'm missing something simple because what I've tried below, produces said error.  Long post, but 99% code, not to complicated, but below mentioned error is received when trying to reinitialize my model - there is some constraint that is expected, but not found.  Really scratching my head over this...any direction would be most appreciated.

```
namespace Deals.Core.DataAccess.Entities
{
   public abstract class Entity<TEntity> : IEntity<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity<TEntity>, new()
   {
      private bool isEmpty;

      protected Entity()
      {
         this.isEmpty = false;
      }

      public static TEntity Empty
      {
         get
         {
            return new TEntity() { IsEmpty = true };
         }
      }

      public bool Active { get; set; }
      public bool Deleted { get; set; }

      [NotMapped]
      public bool IsEmpty
      {
         get
         {
            return this.isEmpty;
         }

         protected set
         {
            this.isEmpty = value;
         }
      }

      public int Version { get; set; }
   }

   public class Site : Entity<Site>, ISite
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
      public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
   }

   public class Survey : Entity<Survey>, ISurvey
   { 
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
   }

   public class User : Entity<User>, IUser
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
      public Guid SiteId { get; set; }
      public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
   }

   public class UserProfile : Entity<UserProfile>, IUserProfile
   {
      public Guid Id { get; set; }
      public virtual User User { get; set; }
   }
}

namespace Deals.Core.DataAccess.Models
{
   public class Context : DbContext, IContext
   {
      public DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
      public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
      public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         this.MapSite(modelBuilder);
         this.MapSurvey(modelBuilder);
         this.MapUser(modelBuilder);
         this.MapUserProfile(modelBuilder);

         Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, ContextConfiguration>());

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      }

      protected virtual void MapSite(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         // Ignore the IsEmpty property.
         this.MapEntity<Site>(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasOptional(p => p.Survey);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasOptional(p => p.Users);
      }

      protected virtual void MapUser(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         // Ignore the IsEmpty property.
         this.MapEntity<User>(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
         modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(p => p.Site).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(p => p.SiteId);
      }

      protected virtual void MapUserProfile(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         // Ignore the IsEmpty property.
         this.MapEntity<UserProfile>(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

         // Why does adding .WillCascadeOnDelete() look for a user_id constraint on UserProfile that does not exist?
         //modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasRequired(p => p.User).WithRequiredPrincipal(user => user.UserProfile);
         //// .WillCascadeOnDelete();
         modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasRequired(p => p.User);
      }

      protected virtual void MapSurvey(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         // Ignore the IsEmpty property.
         this.MapEntity<Survey>(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().HasRequired(p => p.Site);
         //modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasOptional(p => p.Survey).WithOptionalPrincipal().WillCascadeOnDelete();
         modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>().Property(p => p.SurveyXml).HasColumnType("xml").IsRequired();
      }

      #region Generic Mapping
      protected virtual void MapEntity<T>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) where T : Entity<T>, new()
      {
         // Ignore the IsEmpty property.
         modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
            .Ignore(p => p.IsEmpty);
      }

      #endregion Generic Mapping
   }
}
```

SQL generated:

```
create table [dbo].[Sites] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] not null,
    [Url] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Active] [bit] not null,
    [Deleted] [bit] not null,
    [Version] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[Surveys] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] not null,
    [SurveyXml] [xml] not null,
    [Active] [bit] not null,
    [Deleted] [bit] not null,
    [Version] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] not null,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Password] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [LastLogin] [datetime] not null,
    [SiteId] [uniqueidentifier] not null,
    [Active] [bit] not null,
    [Deleted] [bit] not null,
    [Version] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
create table [dbo].[UserProfiles] (
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] not null,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [MiddleInitial] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Honorific] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Active] [bit] not null,
    [Deleted] [bit] not null,
    [Version] [int] not null,
    primary key ([Id])
);
```

Сan't get "on delete cascade" here:

```
alter table [dbo].[Surveys] add constraint [Site_Survey] foreign key ([Id]) references [dbo].[Sites]([Id]);
```

This is good:

```
alter table [dbo].[Users] add constraint [User_Site] foreign key ([SiteId]) references [dbo].[Sites]([Id]) on delete cascade;
```

Can't get "on delete cascade" here:

```
alter table [dbo].[UserProfiles] add constraint [UserProfile_User] foreign key ([Id]) references [dbo].[Users]([Id]);
```

If I do this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
      .HasRequired(p => // p.User)
      .WithRequiredPrincipal(user => user.UserProfile)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete();

 // Instead of this:
 modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>().HasRequired(p => p.User);

 // The sql that is generated looks correct:
 alter table [dbo].[Users] add constraint [UserProfile_User] 
    foreign key ([Id]) references [dbo].[UserProfiles]([Id]) on delete cascade;
```

However, I get this error when trying reinitialize my model when running tests; what's up with FK_dbo.UserProfiles_dbo.Users_Id?

```
Test Name:  SiteRepository_Remove_TestPasses
Test FullName:  Deals.Core.Tests.Deals.Core.DataLibrary.Tests.Integration.SiteRepositoryIntegrationTests.SiteRepository_Remove_TestPasses
Test Source:    c:\Dev\Deals\Deals.Core.Tests\Deals.Core.DataLibrary.Tests\Integration\SiteRepository.Integration.Tests.cs : line 51
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:01.4034458

Result Message: 
Initialization method Deals.Core.Tests.Deals.Core.DataLibrary.Tests.Integration.SiteRepositoryIntegrationTests.TestInitialize threw exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'FK_dbo.UserProfiles_dbo.Users_Id' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors..
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at Deals.Core.DataAccess.UnitOfWorkCore.ForceDatabaseInititialization() in c:\Dev\Deals\Deals.Core.DataAccess\UnitOfWorkCore.cs:line 164
   at Deals.Core.Tests.Deals.Core.DataLibrary.Tests.Integration.SiteRepositoryIntegrationTests.TestInitialize() in c:\Dev\Deals\Deals.Core.Tests\Deals.Core.DataLibrary.Tests\Integration\SiteRepository.Integration.Tests.cs:line 28
```

Comment: Really, really :( Can't you cook this down to the relevant parts for your question? I can't imagine that properties like `Description`, etc. etc. and all summary coments above the properties play any role for your question. Scrolling down through the code to find the important pieces is awful. I have stopped to find them to be honest.

Comment: @Slauma - you serious?  It's not that much code, besides, one person complains there is too much, another you didn't include enough.

Comment: For me this mix of c#, comments, sql, exception messages, irrelevant pieces etc. all in one long section is awful. Nevermind, someone might have the nerves to go through it...

Comment: @Slauma - I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Slauma done, now you can answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This fixed it**

It appears that my database was not being dropped and recreated every test run...

**In my DbContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, ContextConfiguration>());

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      }
```

**My Migration Configuration**

```
public class ContextConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
   {
      public ContextConfiguration()
      {
         this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
         this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
      }
   }
```

**In My Tests**

```
[TestInitialize]
      public override void TestInitialize()
      {
         // Force model updates.
         using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString))
         {
            uow.Database.Initialize(force: false);
         }

         // begin transaction
         this.transactionScope = new TransactionScope();

         this.unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString);
      }
```

**I changed things to this and not no problems**
**I changed things to this and not no problems**
**I changed things to this and not no problems**

**In My Tests**

```
[TestInitialize]
      public override void TestInitialize()
      {
         // Force model updates.

         // I CHANGED TO THIS:
         Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());

         using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString))
         {
            uow.Database.Initialize(force: false);
         }

         // begin transaction
         this.transactionScope = new TransactionScope();

         this.unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Instance.Create<UnitOfWorkCore>(DefaultConnectionString);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete Child Object when Parent Object is deleted, You must configure it from the Parent side of the association. First make `Foreign Key` properties in child objects `[Required]` then the following code.

You should also know that unlike `one-to-many relationships` in `one-to-one relationships` cascading delete is not enabled by default, not even for required relationships. You must always define cascading delete for a one-to-one relationship explicitly:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
                .HasRequired(u => u.User)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.UserProfile)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Survey>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Site)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(c => c.Survey)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: This looks backwards to me the relationship is Site->User->UserProfile | Site -> Survey?

Comment: @gangelo Its had to read your question, anyways. The key note in my answer is `You must always define cascading delete for a one-to-one relationship explicitly`. And make sure that its done from Parent Object.